# How to connect mongodb service by MONGO_URL when the db service is clusterIP?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I separate a meteor app to be 2 containers: app and node. In the world of docker, the app can connect to the node successfully, but in kubernetes, I have difficulties.

My idea is first launching mongodb and creating the mongodb service, and then creating the app to connect the mongodb service, but I am not sure how to let app use MONGO_URL to connect to service's clusterIP.

So, I have a app-deployement showing bellow,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app
  name: mycloud
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: yufang/cloud_docker_app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: MONGO_URL
          value: mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor # here comes the key point. How to specify the service's ip? or use the selector to specify the service's label?
        - name: PORT
          value: "3000"
       - name: ROOT_URL
          value: http://localhost
```

The service is described as bellow,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: mongo
 labels:
  name: mongo
spec:
 ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
 clusterIP: None
 selector:
  app: mongo
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Is MongoDB running on the same cluster or outside of the cluster ?

Comment: Use the service name. The point of a service is to bind a name to an IP that can potentially change. That is: mongodb://mongo:27017

Comment: the service and mongo are on the same node / machine and thanks for @bserdar's help

Comment: There are multiple ways, use one that is suitable for you. Describe the MongoDB service and get the pod IP and use that as mongo host. Or you can also use a service name to connect which is already managed by KubeDNS. You can also create a new service discovery record to point it to mongo service and use that to connect to mongo instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mongodb and mycloud are in the same namespace, then you can use `http://mongodb:27017`

If they are in different namespaces then you can use FQDN `http://mongodb.namespace.svc.cluster.local:27017`

Refer: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/